# Anaconda3 4.3.0 (64-bit) Setup Error Message

Tags: anaconda

Error: Due to incompatibility with several Python libraries, path cannot contain non-ascii characters (special characters or diacritics). Please choose a different path

path is set from browse in installer and has no special characters ?

Comment: Is this related to [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1410) issue?

Comment: Yes this is the same issue thank you  for  sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Found that this is an Anaconda 4.3.0/4.3.0.1 bug caused by the NSIS installer. You can find the bug description posted begin February 2017 [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1410). In that post mingwandroid proposed also a fix proposal that could be integrated in the 4.3.12 release.